# How to run virtual environment in Spyder without Anconda?

Tags: python, spyder, virtual-environment

I want to run virtual environment in Spyder without Anconda or miniconda.
When I change the interpreter for default to my virtual environment,there is a error like this:

```
Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.2.0 and < 2.3.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.

You can install it by running in a system terminal:

conda install spyder‑kernels=2.2

or

pip install spyder‑kernels==2.2.*
```

But how can I install the package  in this virtual environment?
Actually, there is little information  about how to use virtual env in Spyder.
Does everyone provide more info to me? Thanks.

Comment: create virtualenv in terminal at locaiton you want, then in spyder `tool>preference>python interpreter` add the python path of your pythonvenv there and done,. then if you want to install new package then in the terminal open the venv and then run pip install xyz and done

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to activate your virtual environment and install `spyder-kernels` on it with the command provided in the message you posted above. This is better explained in [our docs](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer). I know that's for Anaconda, but the same idea applies for other virtual environment managers.